# Show last modified date

Tags: date, content-management-system, typo3

I am trying to show the last time someone uploaded/changed a file in TYPO3 backend.

I tried something like this

```
<span class="download__specs-item"><f:format.date>now</f:format.date></span>
```

but this is obviously not what i want, i want to see the date that the given file was last modified.

I am not sure how/where to look after something like this

ps: I don't know how to google properly, lol.

Thank you.

Regards,
a TYPO3 beginner.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still looking for the answer, this is how I solved it.

```
<f:debug>{_all}</f:debug>
```

On your page, and click through your available properties.
Here is how it worked for me.

```
<span class="yourclassisprobablyhere">
    <f:format.date format="d M Y">
       {file.originalFile.properties.modification_date}
    </f:format.date>
</span>
```